# Rails joining ActiveRecord relations

Tags: join, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Part of my issue is knowing how to describe what I'm even doing, so please forgive this potential ramble:

OK, so I need to find a list of Addresses, so I have a relation lookup like:

`addresses = Address.where("lower(state) LIKE ? AND lower(city) LIKE ?, state.downcase, city.downcase)`

This works great: I get a list off all addresses where the city and state are the values passed in. Next, I have a `User` that has an array `address_ids` containing all of the IDs of all of the addresses it's associated with. I want to find all of the Users that have any one of the IDs found in the above query. To start, I make an array of all those IDs:

```
id_array = Array.new()
addresses.each do |address|
    id_array.push(address.id)
end
```

Then I take this new array and perform a lookup of Users that has an `address_ids` array that contains any one of the `id_array` values. This is done by:

`applicable_users = User.where('address_ids && ?', '{' + id_array.to_s + '}')`

This also works. Now I have a list of all Addresses that fit a set of criteria, and a list of Users that also match that set of criteria. *NOW* I want to create an array (so I can turn it into JSON and then render it as such) that lists each address and the corresponding users.

The way I'm doing this now is by looping over the `applicable_users`, going through each of their `address_ids`, finding the `address` that I want, and pushing that into a new array, a la:

```
address_array = Array.new()
applicable_users.each do |user|
  user.address_ids.each do |address_id|
    selected_address = addresses.find(address_id.to_i)
    address_array.push([selected_address..., user.first_name, user.last_name])
  end
end
```

Long story short: this is working now, but feels both fragile and needless. Is there a way to join these two ActiveRecord relations so that I can skip the looping/shenanigans?

Even after a couple hours of research, I'm a bit stumped on where to even start, so any direction is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide the code which configures the relationship of the 2 models: User and Address?

Comment: @Hoa Currently there is not one. Addresses kind of belong to Users through an Organization. But it was difficult/impossible to declare that. So Users have an array of Address IDs, but Addresses do not necessarily belong to any User. Perhaps that is where my main issue lies? Not sure how to call that relationship...

Comment: It's possible to declare a relationship in which addresses belong to users through an organization. I can help you with that. What I need from you is to describe the logic of your data. For example: a user belongs to an organization which has many addresses. Once we have the relationship between models configured correctly, the querying part should be straight-forward.

Comment: @Hoa Awesome! That would clean things up. So the way this works (and, necessarily based on the client), is that an Organization :has_many Addresses, and :has_many Users. An address :belongs_to an Organization. A User (An User? huh), also :belongs_to Organizations.

As far as I can tell Users can :has_many Addresses, but Addresses do not REALLY :belong_to Users - they sort of only belong to the Organization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a column named `organization_id` to the `users` table.

Add a column named `organization_id` to the `addresses` table.

Configure the models as follows

```
// app/models/address.rb
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :organization
end

// app/models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :organization
end

// app/models/organization.rb
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
end
```

Then your code will boil down to this

```
addresses = Address.where("lower(state) LIKE ? AND lower(city) LIKE ?", state.downcase, city.downcase)

address_array = Array.new()
addresses.each do |address|
  address.organization.users.each do |user|
    address_array.push([ address, user.first_name, user.last_name ])
  end
end
```

Let me know if you have any questions.